# How to check if circles overlap

Tags: java, graph, encoding, geometry

I'm trying to write a program that checks if a circle contains another circle, if a certain point is inside a circle, or the one I'm having trouble with, if a circle overlaps with another circle.

```
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
public class Problem10_11 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Create circle with certain parameters.
        Circle2D c1 = new Circle2D(2, 2, 5.5);

        //Create output which will be tested by all our methods.
        System.out.println("The area for circle 1 is " +c1.getArea()+ 
                " and its perimeter is " + c1.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("Is (3,3) contained within circle 1? " 
                + c1.contains(3, 3));
        System.out.println("Does circle 1 contain circle 2? " 
                + c1.contains(new Circle2D(4,5,10.5)));
        System.out.println("Does circle 1 overlap with circle 3? " 
                + c1.overlaps(new Circle2D(3, 5, 2.3)));
    }
}
class Circle2D {
    double x; //first parameter
    double y; //second parameter
    double radius; //third parameter

    Circle2D() {
    }
    public Circle2D(double x, double y, double radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;  //set x
    }
    public double getX() {
        return x; //grab x
    }
    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y; //set y
    }
    public double getY() {
        return y; //grab y
    }
    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius; //set radius
    }
    public double getRadius() {
        return radius; //grab radius
    }
    public double getArea() {
            double area = Math.PI*radius*radius; //formula for area
                return area;
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
            double perimeter = 2*Math.PI*radius; //formula for perimeter
                return perimeter;
    }
    public boolean contains(double x, double y) {
        //Use distance formula to check if a specific point is within our circle. 
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x - x, 2) + (Math.pow(this.y - y, 2)));
            if (distance  <= radius * 2)
                return true;
            else {
                return false;
            }
    }
    public boolean contains(Circle2D circle) {
        //Use distance formula to check if a circle is contained within another circle.
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.getX() - x, 2) + (Math.pow(circle.getY() - y, 2)));
        if (distance <= (this.radius - circle.radius)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public boolean overlaps(Circle2D circle) {
        //Use distance formula to check if a circle overlaps with another circle.
            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.getX() - x, 2) + (Math.pow(circle.getY() - y, 2)));



    }
}
```

So my overlap method is all the way at the bottom but I don't really have anything inside because I'm not sure exactly what to do. I tried this :

```
if (distance <= radius) return true;
        else return false;
```

but that didnt work. So I'm not sure what else to try. FYI, I'm trying to check if c1 overlaps with a circle with parameters (3, 5, 2.3). I appreciate any suggestions/advice.

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to [Relative position of two circles](http://mathinschool.com/page/473.html).

```
public boolean overlaps(Circle2D circle) {
        //Use distance formula to check if a circle overlaps with another circle.
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(circle.getX() - x, 2) + (Math.pow(circle.getY() - y, 2)));
        return distance <= (this.radius + circle.radius) and distance >= Math.abs(this.radius - circle.radius)
}
```

Comment: Tried this, still giving me an output of true, when it should be false..

Comment: Awesome, tried multiple scenarios, this does work :) ty!

Answer (score 2):

if the distance between the centres of the circles is less than the sum of the radius of the two circles then they are overlapping.

```
double minDistance = Math.max(circle.getRadius(),this.radius) - Math.min(circle.getRadius(),this.radius);
    if (distance <= (this.radius + circle.getRadius()) && distance>= minDistance) return true;
            else return false;
```

Comment: yes but wouldnt it give out true if the circle is contained inside a circle?

Comment: yes, and they do overlap in that case and also one is contained inside another, if you want `false` in that case you also need a condition that the distance should be more than the radius of bigger of the two circles

Comment: there can be better ways of calculating min distance here but the idea would be same, distance should be more than the difference of the radius of two circles.

Comment: *EDIT* I tried this with a graph that does overlap and it gives me output of false..

Comment: ` you also need a condition that the distance should be more than the radius of bigger of the two circles` doesn't work when the smaller circle's center is inside the bigger circle, yet they still intersect. See my answer for details

Answer (score 1):

Most answers here are wrong.

There are three cases to consider:

1. [image]

Circles overlap and the center of the smaller circle is inside the bigger circle

2. [image]

Circles overlap and the center of the smaller circle is outside the bigger circle

3.[image]

The two circles touch at their borders

The algorithm is this (in Java):

1. Calculate the distance between centers:

```
double centersDistance = Math.sqrt((x2 - x1)^2 + (y2 - y1)^2)
```

2. Check if one circle contains another:

```
boolean blueContainsRed = blue.radius > centersDistance + red.radius;
boolean redContainsBlue = red.radius > centersDistance + blue.radius;
```

3. Check if they overlap:

```
boolean circlesOverlap = centersDistance <= blue.radius + red.radius;
```

the  `<=`  would make sure that  true is returned for case 3 (when borders only touch). If you don't want that, use  `<` .

4. So the final formula would be:

```
return !blueContainsRed && !redContainsBlue && circlesOverlap;
```

This table might also prove useful (from https://planetcalc.com/8098/):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.- you have to to place both circles in space, give them some cordinates
2.- you have to get the vectors from 2 circles.
3.- you have to normailze those vectors and get the correct distance in units, 
 im gonna use pixels.
4.- finally you have to check if the distance between those 2 vectors are less that the radious of both circles, if so, then they are overlaped.

here you have a link that is better explained:
https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769, actually this is something very common we use in game development when we want to check circle collisions ( for 2D games )

Comment: Must have been a mis understanding because this was not helpful to my situation.