# How to check if shapes intersect with one another?

Tags: java

I was wondering how could I check if two shapes intersect with one another. I am required to use custom Shape class, so using java.awt.Shape isn't going to work as a solution. For example if I have two circles that share an area, how would I say that they intersect, how would I check that? I am trying to add methods similar to "bring to front" and "send to back" like you are able to do in PowerPoint, also moving those shapes by one position to front or to back.
Shape class:

```java
public abstract class Shape implements Moveable, Comparable {

    private boolean selected;
    private Color color;

    public abstract void draw(Graphics g);
    public abstract boolean contains(int x, int y);

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

There are multiple classes that extend `Shape` class, I will post `Circle` class. `Fill` and `Area` methods are from `SurfaceShapes` class, which extends `Shape`.

```
public class Circle extends SurfaceShapes {

    private Point center = new Point();
    private int radius;

    public Circle() {
    }

    public Circle(Point center, int radius) {
        this.center = center;
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public Circle(Point center, int radius, boolean selected) {
        this(center, radius);
        setSelected(selected);
    }

    public Circle(Point center, int radius, boolean selected, Color color) {
        this(center, radius, selected);
        setColor(color);
    }

    public Circle(Point center, int radius, boolean selected, Color color, Color innerColor) {
        this(center, radius, selected, color);
        setInnerColor(innerColor);
    }

    public static void metoda() {
        System.out.println("klasa circle");
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Circle) {
            return (this.radius - ((Circle) o).radius);
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveBy(int byX, int byY) {
        this.center.moveBy(byX, byY);
    }

    @Override
    public void fill(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getInnerColor());
        g.fillOval(this.center.getX() - radius + 1, this.center.getY() - radius + 1, radius *2 - 2, radius * 2 - 2);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getColor());
        g.drawOval(this.center.getX() - radius, this.center.getY() - radius, this.radius*2, this.radius*2);
        fill(g);
        if (isSelected()) {
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.drawRect(this.center.getX() - 3, this.center.getY() - 3, 6, 6);
            g.drawRect(this.center.getX() - radius - 3, this.center.getY() - 3, 6, 6);
            g.drawRect(this.center.getX() + radius - 3, this.center.getY() - 3, 6, 6);
            g.drawRect(this.center.getX() - 3, this.center.getY() - radius - 3, 6, 6);
            g.drawRect(this.center.getX() - 3, this.center.getY() + radius - 3, 6, 6);
        }
    }

    public double area() {
        return radius * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        return this.center.distance(x, y) <= radius;
    }

    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        return center.distance(p.getX(), p.getY()) <= radius;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Circle) {
            Circle prosledjeni = (Circle) obj;
            if (this.center.equals(prosledjeni.getCenter()) && this.radius == prosledjeni.getRadius()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Point getCenter() {
        return center;
    }

    public void setCenter(Point center) {
        this.center = center;
    }

    public int getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public void setRadius(int radius) throws Exception {
        if (radius > 0) {
            this.radius = radius;
        } else {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Radius has to be a value greater then 0!");
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Center=" + center + ", radius=" + radius;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49434305/175554 helps ?

Comment: @özkanpakdil thanks this will do for surfaceShapes

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with, it doesn't work 100% but it should do. It needs some refactoring for sure, but it did work for my project. If you want it to be 100% accurate, it needs a change when checking circles (this treats circle as an square), and hexagons. This is the implementation of overlaps method in Circle class.

```
public void overlaps(List<Shape> list, int type, boolean reverse, int oldIndex) {
    int start, end;
    int i = 1;
    int indexOfSelected = list.indexOf(this);
    int oldIndexInNewList = 0;
    if (type == 1) {
        start = i;
        end = list.size();
    } else {
        start = 0;
        end = list.size();
        i = list.size() - 2;
    }
    while (start < end && i >= 0) {
        if (list.get(i) instanceof Rectangle) {
            Rectangle temp = (Rectangle) list.get(i);
            if (Math.abs(this.getCenter().getX() - temp.getCenter().getX()) < Math
                    .abs(this.getRadius() + temp.getWidth() / 2)
                    && Math.abs(this.getCenter().getY() - temp.getCenter().getY()) < Math
                            .abs(this.getRadius() + temp.getHeight() / 2)) {
                if (type == 1) {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, indexOfSelected, i);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, oldIndexInNewList, i);
                } else {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, i, indexOfSelected);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, i, oldIndex);
                }
                return;
            }
        } else if (list.get(i) instanceof Circle) {
            Circle temp = (Circle) list.get(i);
            if (this.getCenter().distance(temp.getCenter().getX(), this.getCenter().getY()) < this.getRadius()
                    + temp.getRadius()) {
                if (type == 1) {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, indexOfSelected, i);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, oldIndexInNewList, i);
                } else {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, i, indexOfSelected);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, i, oldIndex);
                }
                return;
            }
        } else if (list.get(i) instanceof Donut) {
            Donut temp = (Donut) list.get(i);
            if (this.getCenter().distance(temp.getCenter().getX(), this.getCenter().getY()) < this.getRadius()
                    + temp.getRadius()
                    && this.getCenter().distance(temp.getCenter().getX(), this.getCenter().getY())
                            + this.getRadius() > temp.getInnerRadius()
                    || this.getCenter().distance(temp.getCenter().getX(),
                            this.getCenter().getY()) < this.getRadius() + temp.getRadius()
                            && this.getCenter().distance(temp.getCenter().getX(), temp.getCenter().getY())
                                    + temp.getRadius() < this.getRadius()) {
                if (type == 1) {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, indexOfSelected, i);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, oldIndexInNewList, i);
                } else {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, i, indexOfSelected);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, i, oldIndex);
                }
                return;
            }
        } else if (list.get(i) instanceof HexagonAdapter) {
            HexagonAdapter temp = (HexagonAdapter) list.get(i);
            if (this.getCenter().distance(temp.getHexagon().getX(), temp.getHexagon().getY()) < this.getRadius()
                    + temp.getHexagon().getR()) {
                if (type == 1) {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, indexOfSelected, i);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, oldIndexInNewList, i);
                } else {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, i, indexOfSelected);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, i, oldIndex);
                }
                return;
            }
        } else if (list.get(i) instanceof Point) {
            Point temp = (Point) list.get(i);
            if (this.contains(temp)) {
                if (type == 1) {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, indexOfSelected, i);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, oldIndexInNewList, i);
                } else {
                    if (reverse == false)
                        swapShapes(list, i, indexOfSelected);
                    else
                        reverseSwapShapes(list, i, oldIndex);
                }
                return;
            }
        } else if (list.get(i) instanceof Line) {
            Line temp = (Line) list.get(i);
            if (type == 1) {
                if (reverse == false)
                    swapShapes(list, indexOfSelected, i);
                else
                    reverseSwapShapes(list, oldIndexInNewList, i);
            } else {
                if (reverse == false)
                    swapShapes(list, i, indexOfSelected);
                else
                    reverseSwapShapes(list, i, oldIndex);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (type == 1)
            i++;
        else
            i--;
        start++;
    }
}
```

These are codes for swapShapes and reverseSwapShapes, they are in Shape class since other classes extend that one:

```
public void swapShapes(List<Shape> list, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        Collections.swap(list, start, end);
        start++;
    }
}

public void reverseSwapShapes(List<Shape> list, int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        Collections.swap(list, start, end);
        end--;
    }
}
```