# How to know if two circles are intersecting or not? Turtle Graphics

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm learning how to use Turtle-Python and I wanted to know how to write a program that takes as input an x,y center value and radius for two circles, draws them in a turtle window, and prints whether they intersect or not.

PD: I haven't learned much so it would be great to see some simple code so I understand what's going on

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Calculate the distance between the two points (D = sqrt( (x1-x2)² + (y1-y2)² ) ). If this distance is bigger than the sum of the radii of the two circles, then they do not intersect.

Comment: Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433930/how-to-check-if-circles-overlap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if circles overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433930/how-to-check-if-circles-overlap)

Comment: Stackoverflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

If we make the circles themselves turtles, rather than drawing circles, then we can simply use turtle's own `distance()` method to achieve this:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_RADIUS = 10

screen = Screen()

x1, y1, radius1 = screen.textinput("Green Circle", "Please enter: x y radius").split(maxsplit=3)

turtle1 = Turtle()
turtle1.shape('circle')
turtle1.color('green')
turtle1.shapesize(int(radius1) / CURSOR_RADIUS)
turtle1.penup()
turtle1.goto(int(x1), int(y1))

x2, y2, radius2 = screen.textinput("Red Circle", "Please enter: x y radius").split(maxsplit=3)

turtle2 = Turtle()
turtle2.shape('circle')
turtle2.color('red')
turtle2.shapesize(int(radius2) / CURSOR_RADIUS)
turtle2.penup()
turtle2.goto(int(x2), int(y2))

if turtle1.distance(turtle2) < int(radius1) + int(radius2):
    marker = Turtle()
    marker.hideturtle()
    marker.write("Overlap!", align='center', font=('Arial', 24, 'bold'))

screen.exitonclick()
```